# sp_MSforeachdb MS SQL error

Tags: sql-server, sp-msforeachdb

This is for MS SQL 2005:  Anyone know why the first succeeds, then creating two of the same statement in succession fails?  All the statements are exactly the same.  Changing the double quote to two single quotes has the same effect.

> sp`_`MSforeachdb @command1 = 'if (left("?", 2) = "p`_`") begin; print "?"; end;';
>
> produces
>
> p`_`NationalBrands
>   p`_`NonBrand
>   p`_`Database`_`Name`_`That`_`Begins`_`With`_`P`_`Underbar

but

> sp`_`MSforeachdb @command1 = 'if (left("?", 2) = "p`_`") begin; print "?"; end;';
>   sp`_`MSforeachdb @command1 = 'if (left("?", 2) = "p`_`") begin; print "?"; end;';
>
> produces
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'sp_MSforeachdb'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple stored proc calls in the same batch each one needs EXEC(UTE)

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command1 = 'if (left(''?'', 2) = ''p_'') begin; print ''?''; end;';
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command1 = 'if (left(''?'', 2) = ''p_'') begin; print ''?''; end;';
```

I'd always use 2 x single quote not double quote to avoid issues with the QUOTED_IDENTIFERS environment setting.

Comment: Actually, only calls subsequent to the first need the exec. (Personally I would put it on both as a matter of style, but it is not required)

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly use Exec when you are calling multiple procs in that manner, try

```
sp_MSforeachdb @command1 = 'if (left("?", 2) = "p_") begin; print "?"; end;';
exec sp_MSforeachdb @command1 ='if(left("?", 2) = "p_") begin; print "?"; end;';
```

from the documentation for [Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

> Using EXECUTE with Stored Procedures
>
> You do not have to specify the EXECUTE
>   keyword when you execute stored
>   procedures when the statement is the
>   first one in a batch.